# Shift rows left based on column value

Tags: r

I'm working with a large data frame (30000+ observations with 20 variables) so I can't transpose my data frame. For some rows, some columns are shifted to the right of a Date-class column, but columns to the left of the Date-class column aren't shifted. I tried writing an `if` statement based on the column where the shift occurs, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. 
Here's some example code:

```
structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
Vial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), Date = structure(c(15156, 15156, 15156, 
15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 
15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156, 15156), class = "Date"), 
Value_1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", 
"2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-01", 
"2011-07-01", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a"), Value_2 = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), Value_3 = c("c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), Value_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note that the last column contains `NA`'s but also values.

Comment: What code have you tried? Are you "guaranteed" that there are no "date-like" elements in the first column after `$Date`?

Comment: How are you getting the data? If from a file, then let's look at some problem rows form the file. If from a process (e.g., `httr::GET` and some API), then it might help to look at the process that takes that reply and turns it into a frame. Regardless, while it is not too hard to fix this bug, it might be better to fix it upstream where the problem originates.

Comment: I am guaranteed there are no "date-like" elements after `$Date`. I tried to go after the string length since the `$Date` column will contain 10 characters but the columns to the right won't

Comment: The only reason I want to fix this problem downstream is because I have ~50 files to analyze, all with 30k+ rows, so doing this upstream would be very time-intensive. The files are being sent directly to me as .txt files and I don't have control of the data before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I urge again that the upstream process *should* be fixed. In the interim, this hack should work "well-enough" for now.

```r
nadate <- is.na(x$Date)
newdate <- as.Date(x$Value_1[nadate])
newnotna <- !is.na(newdate)
x$Date[nadate] <- newdate[newnotna]
ind <- seq(which(colnames(x) == "Date") + 1L, ncol(x) - 1L)
x[nadate & newnotna, ind] <- x[nadate & newnotna, ind + 1L]
x[nadate & newnotna, ncol(x)] <- NA
x
#    Site Vial       Date Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
# 1     1    1 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 2     1    2 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 3     1    3 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 4     1    4 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 5     1    5 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 6     1    6 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 7     1    7 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 8     1    8 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 9     1    9 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 10    1   10 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 11    2    1 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 12    2    2 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 13    2    3 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 14    2    4 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 15    2    5 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 16    2    6 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 17    2    7 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 18    2    8 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 19    2    9 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 20    2   10 2011-07-01       a       b       c    <NA>
# 21    3    1 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 22    3    2 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 23    3    3 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 24    3    4 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 25    3    5 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 26    3    6 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 27    3    7 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 28    3    8 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 29    3    9 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
# 30    3   10 2011-07-01       a       b       c       d
```

This should be stable-enough: if run multiple times on the same data, it should do nothing more. If the `$Date` column is not `NA`, then no shift is attempted. If `$Value_1` does not parse as a date, nothing is shifted.